# phpmyadmin access denied xampp #1130

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

hello i am still confused when i restert my Laptop then my Xammp server is not working. 
it start normalily. 
but its give me this error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWiWh.png

[but its give me this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWiWh.png)

i got to this location \Xampp\phpMyAdmin\
and open this config.inc 
and

change $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

to

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'abc123';
but it still not work.

Know other method i changed

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';

to

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
but know its give me this error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Dn7.png

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Dn7.png)

[but know its give me this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2K25.png)

Comment: Before getting the first error, did you modify the phpMyAdmin configuration from what XAMPP ships by default? Normally it comes configured so that you can connect to your database. If you don't have any important data stored, I would strongly suggest a complete removal and re-installation.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to incorrect mysql user permission settings - where mysql server is not allowing the user (with which you are trying to connect & for XAMPP, probably it is "root") to connect from localhost. You need to GRANT this user access to all or specific database from localhost.

## E.g.

## GRANT ALL ON yourdbname.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'rootpassword'

Do replace the dbname & password as per your configuration.

Comment: how can i do please give me example